# how to count distinct values for data with too many columns in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I had problem when processing data with a large number of columns in spark.

I am currently using countDistinct function as follows:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
distinct_cnts = df.agg(*(F.countDistinct(col).alias(col) for col in df.columns)).toPandas().T[0].to_dict()
```

for data with 3300 columns and only 50 rows(sampled data around 1mb)

I am using spark cluster environment(1gb for driver and executor).

When I tried to run the above function, I ran into memory problem and stackoverflow error.

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

I don't really understand how the data around 1mb cause memory issue. Could anyone explain about this?

When I tried to allocate more memory to the spark driver and executors(3gb for each and setting dynamicAllocation), the above function works but another computation jobs for every column cause the same issue again. 
for example function as follows:

```
df.select(*(F.sum(F.col(c).isNull().cast('int')).alias(c) for c in f.columns)).toPandas().T[0].to_dict()
```

Is there any other way to solve this problem besides the spark configuration? (better way to write code)

Comment: You can try to create a md5 based on all columns concatenation (both built-in Functions). Something like md5(concat_ws("|",yourColumns))

Comment: @baitmbarek Thank you so much for your help. The reason why I need to concatenate all the columns to calculate the unique value of each column is still confusing. Could you specify on this in more detail? And if you know the logic behind consuming so much memory when processing only 1mb of data, could you please explain on this too?

Comment: After reading your question again I think I didn't understand your problem well enough. For now you have "huge" objects, each record being a 3300 field structure. It's quite heavy in memory and cannot be distributed (every attribute being related to a specific record). You should consider splitting your main DataFrame into multiple Small Dataframes, reduce them with the "union" operator, then compute some kind of reduceByKey / combineByKey on each column name. I could share a Spark / Scala example if you think it may help.

Comment: So instead of using "countDistinct", you mean I need to use RDD function i.e. reduceByKey, etc. to calculate unique values of each column? And if possible, please share spark example with me in here?

Comment: Exactly, thats what I mean. I'll try to provide some example in answer in the next few hours

Answer (score 0):

Here are two approaches you can try/challenge, but written in Scala. Note, I didn't test it yet on wide dataframes, but feel free to share some anonymized data if possible :

Lets say we have a wide DataFrame (here with only 6 columns) :

```
val wideDF = Seq(
    ("1","a","b","c","d","e","f"),
    ("2","a","b","c","d2","e","f"),
    ("3","a","b","c2","d3","e","f"),
    ("4","a2","b2","c3","d4","e2","f2")
  ).toDF("key","col1","col2","col3","col4","col5","col6")

+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|key|col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|col6|
+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|  1|   a|   b|   c|   d|   e|   f|
|  2|   a|   b|   c|  d2|   e|   f|
|  3|   a|   b|  c2|  d3|   e|   f|
|  4|  a2|  b2|  c3|  d4|  e2|  f2|
+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

**Approach 1 :**

Here, I take all the DF columns (3300) and create 100 buckets, containing 33 columns each. My buckets can be parallelized for better scalability :

```
val allColumns = wideDF.columns.grouped(100).toList

val reducedDF = allColumns.par.map{colBucket:Array[String] =>
    //We will process aggregates on narrowed dataframes
    wideDF.select(colBucket.map(c => countDistinct($"$c").as(s"distinct_$c")):_*)
  }.reduce(_ join _)

reducedDF.show(false)

+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|distinctcol1|distinctcol2|distinctcol3|distinctcol4|distinctcol5|distinctcol6|
+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|2           |2           |3           |4           |2           |2           |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

**Approach 2** :

Create (or use Panda's) Transpose method, then aggregate on column name (could also be done with RDD API)

```
def transposeDF(dataframe: DataFrame, transposeBy: Seq[String]): DataFrame = {
    val (cols, types) = dataframe.dtypes.filter{ case (c, _) => !transposeBy.contains(c)}.unzip
    require(types.distinct.size == 1)

    val kvs = explode(array(
      cols.map(c => struct(lit(c).alias("column_name"), col(c).alias("column_value"))): _*
    ))

    val byExprs = transposeBy.map(col)

    dataframe
      .select(byExprs :+ kvs.alias("_kvs"): _*)
      .select(byExprs ++ Seq($"_kvs.column_name", $"_kvs.column_value"): _*)
  }

// We get 1 record per key and column name
transposeDF(wideDF, Seq("key")).groupBy("column_name").agg(countDistinct($"column_value").as("distinct_count")).show(false)

+-----------+--------------+
|column_name|distinct_count|
+-----------+--------------+
|col3       |3             |
|col4       |4             |
|col1       |2             |
|col6       |2             |
|col5       |2             |
|col2       |2             |
+-----------+--------------+
```